# Error : -7132: An error occurred streaming ISSetup.dll support file Script Files\Setup.inx

Tags: installshield, installscript

I have `installscript` in Basic MSI Installshield Project which works perfectly when using InstallShield 2015 IDE. But, when using Installshield cmdline on a separate machine, getting this error -

> "Error : -7132: An error occurred streaming ISSetup.dll support file
>   ..\Script Files\Setup.inx" .

All the necessary files are in place for building Installshield project.There are other projects which are using same installscript and running absolutely fine using Installshield cmdline on the same machine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I believe `Setup.inx` is your compiled `Setup.rul`(the default `Installscript file` included in all Installshield setups that use Installscript custom actions). I suppose you have to check whether that source file is actually being compiled at all, or check whether it is in a different location than usual? I don't have the tool available to test.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the separate machine is a different environment.
Different environment, different file locations.

That kind of compilation error is usually related with link files problems. Like a linked rul not available.

Check the relative links to every .rul in your project, specially if you have custom .rul files.